# Execute CTE if parameter is passed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a stored procedure with a few CTE's. For example:

```
create or alter proc sp_test
    (@param1 int,
     @param2 int,
     @param3 int)
as
begin
    ;with cte_a as
    (
        select * 
        from table_a 
        where param1 = @param1
    ),
    cte_b as 
    (
        select * 
        from table_b 
        where param2 = @param2
    )
    ....

   //what I would like
   if @param3 > 0
   begin
       cte_c as 
       (select * from table_c)
   end
end
```

Is there a way to define a cte that could be used with the previous defined cte's only if a parameter is passed?

PS: I know I could start with the parameter checking and add an else statement, but this stored procedure is very large and I think this way would be simpler (if possible).

Comment: I think the closest you will get is to add `WHERE @param3 > 0` to the end of cte_c

Comment: A CTE is, as its name suggests, a table **expression**. It's not an object. You can't define it, not use it, and then attempt to reference it later in another statement. This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you *really* trying to achieve here?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your use case, you can go for temporary tables or table variables, as CTEs lose the scope immediately after subsequent select statement.

[Reference from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> **Common Table Expression**
> Specifies a temporary named result set, known as a common table expression (CTE). This is derived from a
> simple query and defined within the execution scope of a single
> SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or MERGE statement.

```sql
select * INTO #cte_a
from table_a 
where param1 = @param1

select * INTO #cte_b
from table_b 
where param2 = @param2
 
//what I would like
if @param3 > 0
begin
      select * INTO #cte_c from table_c 
end
```